# How can I access a external variable from an anonymous function?

Tags: php

This is my function

```
function sample($greet, $otherVar) {

   $codigo = preg_replace_callback("/(**_(\w+))/",

      function($matches) use ($greet) {

          if($matches[1] == $otherVar) { 

            (...)
```

The point is.. My principal function recieve **$otherVar** as parameter.. And I would like to use this value inside the anonymous function..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do that through the `use` keyword, just like you already do for the `$greet` variable. So like this:

```
function($matches) use ($greet, $otherVar) {
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I'll set you answer as the best one as soon as possible (10 minutes).